# Final/const in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, final

```
    void main() {
      const pizzaPrices = {
        'Margherita' : 5.5,
        'Pepperoni' : 7.5,
        'Vegetarian' : 6.5,
      };
      var sum = 0.0;
      const order = ['Margherita', 'Pepperoni'];
      for (var item in order){
        final price = pizzaPrices[item];
...
      }
    }
```

`final price = pizzaPrices[item];` the rest of the code is supposed to print the total price of the order, i dont get why `final` works in this case? isnt the point of final is to not allow a variable to change?

Comment: Where do you think you are changing any variable in this snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `final price` for each loop iteration. You will only be able to use `price` within the current loop iteration and a new `final price` is being created on the next iteration.

---

`final` variables can be assigned a value when declared, but can't be re-assigned. You won't be able to assign a value to `price` again in the same loop iteration.

As I understand, `const` is assigned a hard-coded value and can never be changed. `final` can be assigned once during runtime and can never be changed.